# Continuing a loop for a proc within a proc

Tags: tcl

How do I increase the recursion limit in TCL. My nested recursive proc is erroring out.

```
proc a {arg} {
   a $arg
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [**interp recursionlimit** *path ?newlimit?*](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm#M24) command.

The name of the "current" interpreter is the empty string.

```
$ tclsh
% proc a {} { incr ::n; a }
% set n 0
0
% a
too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)
% set n
1000
% interp recursionlimit ""
1000
% interp recursionlimit "" 4000
4000
% set n 0
0
% a
too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)
% set n
4000
```

Heed the warning in the documentation:

> The command sets the maximum size of the Tcl call stack only. It cannot by itself prevent stack overflows on the C stack being used by the application. If your machine has a limit on the size of the C stack, you may get stack overflows before reaching the limit set by the command. If this happens, see if there is a mechanism in your system for increasing the maximum size of the C stack.

Comment: If you're using Tcl 8.6 and have plenty of memory, recursion limits can be enormous; I've used depths of a million and more just fine.